# Is the hadith "...no superiority of an Arab over a non-Arab ... or a black person over a red person..." authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> The Prophet sallallaahu `alayhi  wa  sallam (may Allaah exalt his mention), said: "O, people, indeed your Lord is One and your father is one. Know that there is no superiority of an Arab over a non-Arab, or a non-Arab over an Arab, or a red person over a black person, or a black person over a red person - except by piety."

Is this hadith authentic? I hear it mentioned a lot.  I believe it is in musnad ahemd or one of the sirah narrations? But I didn't find mention of Black over Red Persons etc.